# Composables inside composable

Tags: vuejs3, vue-reactivity, composable

I'd like to use composables inside composables, but it turned out, that composables lose reactivity.
Please, give me advice how to tackle this problem.
The desired behavior is beneath:

```js
import {ref, computed} from "vue";
import useFirstStep from "components/draft/use/useFirstStep";
import useSecondStep from "components/draft/use/useSecondStep";

export default function useFifthStep() {
    const {isValidFirstStep} = useFirstStep();
    const {isValidSecondStep} = useSecondStep();

    const isValidStep = computed(() => {
        return isValidFirstStep.value &&
            isValidSecondStep.value &&
    });
    return {isValidStep};
}
```

Comment: give a demo to know more your example.

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to say without seeing the example code from `useFirstStep` and `useSecondStep`, but I bet you have a ref inside export, but you should keep it outside, so that whenever you use this composable you would not initialize given ref.
So `useFirstStep.js` should look like:

```
const isValidFirstStep = ref(false)

export default function useFirstStep() {
  // some logic to set isValidFirstStep

  return {isValidFirstStep};
}
```